# Servidores soluçando?

Tags: bug

Isto aconteceu comigo há pouco, em duas ou três tentativas de carregar a home do site:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recarregando mais uma vez, voltou a funcionar. Pode ter sido algo aqui do meu lado, mas achei melhor reportar mesmo assim.

Comment: Eu vi esse erro agora pouco também...

Comment: Anda tem algumas lentidões, não sei se está relacionado. Também não sei se o fato de só os destaques aparecerem no boletim da comunidade tem alguma coisa a ver também.

Comment: Ocorreu comigo tambem, achei q era algo temporario

Comment: Acabei de ver esse erro no meta... O____o

Comment: A imagem não aparece pra mim

Comment: De vez em qdo as perguntas somem, pouco depois voltam.

Comment: @Gabe Isso deve ser outro bug :) A mensagem de erro diz *It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma botnet se engraçou e começou a vasculhar nosso site, o que fez com que a engine de tags desse uma leve... soluçada.

O Marc Gravell deu uma olhada e acredita ter mitigado o problema. Avisem se virem mais alguma coisa.

Comment: link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295481/